# Python, large files

Tags: python, xml, csv

I'm trying to open a 100GB file in python, this is the stack overflow archive (https://archive.org/download/stackexchange zip file name stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z content Posts.xml) of posts from 2008 to present (2023). the problem is that this file is too big, the pc has a lot of difficulty processing it and it could take several hours or days to examine it. I have to put the xml file in csv, but I'm only interested in posts with the year 2022 which would probably be less than 5GB out of the total 100GB. I tried to open the file in many ways, I tried to "cut" 70% of the file i.e. start reading after 70% of the content as the most recent data is found at the bottom of the file but I couldn't.
How can I do this?
I certainly know that the first 70GB are not needed because this was the size in 2019.
ChatGPT failed to help me.

so that's how I did it in the beginning analyzing everything:

```
'''
    This script takes a raw xml file as input and outputs
    an almost clean csv file
'''

import re, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# file paths
IN = 'C:\\Users\\.....\\Desktop\\StackOverflow archive\\Posts.xml' #raw xml file
OUT = 'C:\\Users\\.....\\Desktop\\StackOverflow archive\\almostCleanPosts.csv' #almost clean csv file

# regex patterns
TAG_PATTERN = re.compile('<|>')
NEW_LINE = re.compile('\n')
BODY_1 = re.compile('\n?<pre(.*?)><code>(.*?)<\/code><\/pre>\n?|<div class=".*<div class=".*>', flags=re.S)
BODY_2 = re.compile('\s?<code>\w*<\/code>.\s?|\s?<a href=.*\">|<\/a>')
BODY_3 = re.compile('\s?<\w*>|<\/\w*>(.|\s)?')
BODY_4 = re.compile('&nbsp;|http(s?)://\S*|<img src.*">|<br/>*|br>|<br />*|<ol.*">|/p>|/strong>|/li>|&lt;key>|&lt;/key>|/code>|/a>|#?&\w\w\w?;?')

# method to clean instances using regex
def cleanup(dirty):
    clean = re.sub(NEW_LINE,' ', dirty)    
    clean = re.sub(BODY_1,' ', clean)
    clean = re.sub(BODY_2,' ', clean)
    clean = re.sub(BODY_3,' ', clean)
    clean = re.sub(BODY_4,' ', clean)
    return clean


open(OUT, 'w').close() # erase file berfore writing
with open(IN, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as inFile, open(OUT, 'a') as outFile: 
    outFileWriter = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter=';')
    outFileWriter.writerow(['id', 'post', 'title', 'tags']) # write header
    
    for post in inFile:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(post, "lxml") # get xml tree
        line = soup.find("row")
        newRow = [] # new list to append as a row to the output file
        try:
            #date = line.attrs['creationdate'] #decomment to get 2022
            #if date.startswith("2022"):
                typeId = line.attrs['posttypeid']
                newRow.append(line.attrs['id']) # first field 

                if typeId == '1': #is a question
                    newRow.append(cleanup(line.attrs['body'])) # second field
                    newRow.append(line.attrs['title']) # third field
                    newRow.append(re.sub(TAG_PATTERN,' ', line.attrs['tags'])) # fourth field

                elif typeId == '2': #is an answer, title and tags attributes are missing      
                    newRow.append(cleanup(line.attrs['body'])) # second field 
                    # leave title and tag fields empty
                    newRow.append('') # third field
                    newRow.append('') # fourth field
                
                outFileWriter.writerow(newRow) # append cleaned row tothe file
            
        except:
            pass
```

i expect to get all posts from 2022 in csv format, please help me.

Comment: What happens when you run this program?

Comment: i already texted it. run unstopped for a lot of time, 30 minutes to generate 1GB in csv after i stopped i cant wait 100*30

Comment: `open(OUT, 'w').close()` is unnecessary. It's not *closing* the file that truncates it, it's opening it in `w` mode in the first place. You can drop this line, and use `with ..., open('OUT', 'w') as outFile:`.

Comment: ok thank you, useful info but how to get from 100GB with all post only probably 5GB of 2022?

Comment: What's the problem with looking only at the last 30%?

Comment: how to do it? pandas failed "file to much big"

Comment: One general approach can be to use `mmap` to map the file into memory and run regular expressions over it (or parts of it). These regexes must use byte string patterns to work.

Comment: can you edit the to do it?

Comment: There are several ways to process huge XML files. Using [tag:sax] is one of them. Other techniques are [tag:iterparse] (available in ElementTree and lxml) and streaming [tag:xslt]. Many similar questions with answers already exist here on SO.

Comment: please make an answer or edit the code to do it show how to do it please?

Comment: you said xml.etree.ElementTree? also chatgpt but wasnt high performance

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using Powershell.  Following code read first 100 rows

```
using assembly System.Xml
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$FILENAME = "c:\temp\posts.xml"

$reader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($FILENAME)
$lines = 0
write-Host "START"
while($reader.EOF -eq $False)
{
   $lines++
   if($lines -eq 100) { break}
   if ($reader.Name -ne "row")
   {
      $reader.ReadToFollowing("row") | out-null
   }
   if ($reader.EOF -eq $False)
   {
       $element = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::ReadFrom($reader)
       Write-Host "ID = " $element.Attribute("Id").Value
       Write-Host "PostTypeId = " $element.Attribute("PostTypeId").Value
       Write-Host "ParentId = " $element.Attribute("ParentId").Value
       Write-Host "CreationDate = " $element.Attribute("CreationDate").Value
       Write-Host "Score = " $element.Attribute("Score").Value
       Write-Host "Body = " $element.Attribute("Body").Value
       Write-Host "OwnerUserId = " $element.Attribute("OwnerUserId").Value
       Write-Host "LastActivityDate = " $element.Attribute("LastActivityDate").Value
       Write-Host "CommentCount = " $element.Attribute("CommentCount").Value
       Write-Host "ContentLicense = " $element.Attribute("ContentLicense").Value
   }
}
```